# How to call & await async C# method from Lua / MoonSharp script?

Tags: c#, lua, moonsharp

I would like to call & await a C# async method from Lua / MoonSharp code.

For example:

1).

```
async void Test1() {
    await Something();
}
```

2).

```
async Task Test2() {
    await Something();
}
```

And then calling it from Lua - 1). does not await but continues script execution, and 2). throws `` ScriptRuntimeException: cannot convert clr type System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]
MoonSharp.Interpreter.Interop.Converters.ClrToScriptConversions.ObjectToDynValue `` exception.

Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: The converter probably does not know how to convert the state machine generated. What do you want to do in the end? You will likely need to do  a synchronous block with `Something.Wait()`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am making a simple mod system for Unity game. Some C# methods needs to be async (for example loading asset bundles - so to not block the rendering loop). And I need to call them from - in this case - mod's InitScript.lua (because game itself does not know much about what to load etc - the game just provides an api for Lua scripts.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i've also tried `Something.Wait()` as you mentioned, but no luck - it freezes entire Unity editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally gone with callbacks. I don't think it's a good solution, though. **So if anyone have a better one i'll be more than happy to change the accepted answer**.

For anyone interested here's how to make the callbacks work in MoonSharp:

Lua / MoonSharp

```
SomethingAsync(10, function()
    SomePrintFunction('async work done')
end)
```

C#

```
async void SomethingAsync(int whatever, DynValue callback) {
    await SomeAsyncWorkBeingDone();

    if (callback.Type == DataType.Function) {
        callback.Function.Call();
    }
}
```

More info can be found in the [doc's](http://www.moonsharp.org/dynvalue.html).