# How to call & await async C# method from Lua / MoonSharp script with arguments?

Tags: c#, lua, moonsharp

There is a pretty similar question asked here: [How to call & await async C# method from Lua / MoonSharp script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687687/how-to-call-await-async-c-sharp-method-from-lua-moonsharp-script)

But this doesn't account for arguments. I want this for example to run:

```cs
private async Task<string> GetNicknameAsync(ulong id)
{
    return await GetNicknameCodeAsync(id);
}
```

And then be able to do something like this in lua:

```lua
print(getNickname(372983297329234))
```

Comment: You just need to add the args to the answer in the other question. you would do `function(result) print(result) end` for the lua `callback`. then you just put the result in the `callback.Function.Call(nickName);`

Comment: Yeah that much I understood, but is there no way to make it prettier? As in just having to do `print(getNickname(id))`?

Comment: with no additional lua code? if additional lua code is fine then you define a function that wraps your async function and does all the `callback`, then you have that function accept the `id` pass it to the async and return the result to your print

Comment: Hmm, I'll try, thanks.

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this? I am looking for something similar.